# Preventing the activation of the menu from around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that has a series of animations that are activated by clicking on an element or hovering over it ( hover:change in opacity, click: highlight the clicked element, menu moves to the left, and dividers fade in). However all these activities can be activated by clicking around the menu and anywhere. Anyway to solve it?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/8740qte8/

HTML:

```
<div id="logo" class="logo" ><img src="logo.png"/></div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
             <li id="item1"><button>AAAAAAAA</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button>BBBBBBB</button></li>
            <li id="item3"><button>CCCCCCCC        </button></li>
            <li id="item4"><button>DDDDDDD         </button></li>
            <li id="item5"><button>EEEEEEEE EEE.   </button></li>
            <li id="item6"><button>FFFFFFFFF       </button></li>
            <li id="item7"><button>GGGGGGGGG       </button></li>
<!--                  <li> <input type="button" value="animation" OnClick="checklist(this)"> </input>
  </li>-->
        </ul>
        </div>


      <div id="container">
          <div class='container'>
<div id="first" class="inner-container">
<div class="ism-slider">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div id="item11" class="item"> <a name="item11"></a>
       <div class="content">

                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="item11" class="item"> <a name="item11"></a>
       <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div id="item11" class="item"> <a name="item11"></a>
       <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}

body.no-vscroll {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    max-width:1600px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 1.3em;
}
.custom-class {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top:-115px;
    margin-right: 26px;
    font-family:"verdana";

}
a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}
samp {
    display: none;
}
img {
    -webkit-animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    background: transparent;
    border-style:none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}
.logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:40px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align:center;
    border-style: none;
}


.menu li {
    position: relative;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0px;
}
#item7 {
    transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    margin-left:105px;
}
#item6 {
    transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    margin-left: 95px;
}
#item5 {
    transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
#item4 {
    transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    margin-left: 123px;
}
#item3 {
    transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    margin-left: 113px;
}
#item2 {
    transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
#item1 {
    transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    margin-left: 117px;
}

#item1>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item2>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item3>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item4>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item5>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item6>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item7>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}

.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: -33%;
}

.headlines li {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#000000;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headlines:hover li, .headlines.active li {
    /* PARENT HOVER */
    opacity:0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Dim all */
}
.headlines li:hover, .headlines li.active {
    /* SINGLE HOVER */
    opacity: 1;
    /* Max one */
    color:#000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#first
{   display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 2px;

}
#first img 
{
     height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#second
{
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 170px;
    margin-top: -215px;

}
#second img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#third
{
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -215px;

}
#third img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}



@-webkit-keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}

}

<!-- slider css-->

#wrapper {
    width: 10%;
    padding: px 0;

}

#slider-container {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    height: 1350px;
    top:-18%;
    left: -20px;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slider-view-area {

    max-height: 300px;

}

#nav img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:grey;
    width:40px;
    height:30px;


}
#prev {
    margin-left: 540px;
    font-size: 10px;

}
#next {
    right: -40px;
    margin-top: 13px;

}

#mask {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 100%;

}

.item {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;

}
.content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 17%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:  10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 
    margin: auto;

    position: relative;
}
.content a {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 170px;
}
.selected {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
  $(document).on('click','#item1', function()
{ 
    $("#container").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(".inner-container").hide();
        $("#first").show();
        $("#container").fadeIn(1000);
    });

});


    $(".menu").on("click", function () {
  $(".menu").addClass('permahover');

});


        var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function() {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);

    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the size of your links.  I'm not seeing the cause (mostly because I'm not going to read through all your CSS) but if you can find what's causing the padding around the words you will fix the issue.